# Ruby on rails string parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text-parsing, xml-parsing

I have a string that is a bunch of XML tags.

Basically there is the contents to one tag I want and ignore everything else:

The input would look like:

```
<Some><XML><stuff>
<title type='text'>key</title>
<Some><other><XML><stuff>
```

The output would look like:

```
key
```

I'm not sure if XML is appropriate since there doesn't seem very much structure to this particular XML.

Can regex do this in RoR or is it more of just a pattern matching thing (true or false) in ruby on rails?

Thanks so much!

Cheers,
Zigu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). If your source *could* not be strictly valid XML, I strongly suggest you to use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Handle the source as an HTML document and extract the info you need in this way:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("Your string with <key>some value</key>"))
doc.search('key').each do |value|
  puts value.content # do whatever you want
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's why you don't parse xml with regexen: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)